# Storing multiple ids in a single (SQL) row?

Tags: mysql, database

So I want to make a webapp that needs to store the following.

"Users"
some "Events"
and some "Customers"

each "Event" has a "User" which is represented by a userId column.

But each "Event" can have multiple customers, to be able to store all this info,
I thought it's better to have a new table "Customers_In_Events" that has 3 columns:

```
id,     -- Not sure if that's needed
e_id    -- Event ID
c_id    -- Customer ID
```

I have 2 questions...

- Is there some better way to do this?
- If I decide to go with the way I mentioned (an extra table), Would the "id" column be needed?

I am using MySQL by the way.

Comment: what would "id" represent?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I am asking if it's needed or not (I was thinking i need a primary key)

Comment: the PK can just be a composite key of e_id,c_id

Comment: Ohh, and is there no better way do it? I feel like creating a whole table for this is an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bridge model to represent your data, which is also normalized.

- every event can have multiple customers
- every customer can have multiple events

so the tabkes would look like

```
Events    events_coustmers     cutonuers
e_id(PK)  e_id(fk)             c_id(Pk)
e_name    c_id(fk)             c_name
          PK(e_id,c_id)
```